# Error 1005 thrown in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to run 5 create tables statements. 3 of them are working fine with the foreign keys I've declared, however the tables **'generalweather'** and **'userreg'** are throwing the error 1005, which I know has to do with some mismatch in my foreign keys. I've been looking for the error, but I can't find it anywhere. What is wrong with those two create table statements? (My default schema is titled "tester")

```
 CREATE TABLE `coastal` (
  `Date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Time` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `AM/PM` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Location` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Tide Description` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Estimated Swell(ft)` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Wind Speed(mph)` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Wind Direction` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Visibility (%)` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Date`,`Time`,`Location`,`AM/PM`),

  CONSTRAINT `coastalFK`
  FOREIGN KEY (Date, Time, Location, `AM/PM`)
  REFERENCES tester.locations (Date, Time, Location, `AM/PM`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,

  INDEX `DateFK_idx` (`Date` ASC) , 
  INDEX `TimeFK_idx` (`Time` ASC) ,
  INDEX `AM/PMFK_idx` (`AM/PM` ASC) , 
  INDEX `LocationFK_idx` (`Location` ASC)
);


CREATE TABLE `generalweather` (
`Date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`Location` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`ClimateDescription` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Average Temperature(F)` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`Elevation(ft)` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`Recommended Activity` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Date`,`Location`,`ClimateDescription`),

CONSTRAINT `generalweatherFK`
FOREIGN KEY (Date, Location)
REFERENCES tester.locations (Date, Location)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,

INDEX `DateFK_idx` (`Date` ASC) , 
INDEX `LocationFK_idx` (`Location` ASC)
);


CREATE TABLE `locations` (
`Date` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Time` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`AM/PM` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`Location` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Location Type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`Temperature (F)` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Date`,`Time`,`Location`,`AM/PM`)
);


CREATE TABLE `precipitation` (
`Date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`Time` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`AM/PM` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`Location` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Precipitation Chance (%)` text,
`Wind Speed(mph)` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`Wind Direction` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`Visibility (%)` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`Humidity (%)` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Date`,`Time`,`AM/PM`,`Location`),
CONSTRAINT `DateFK`
FOREIGN KEY (Date, Time, Location, `AM/PM`)
REFERENCES tester.locations (Date, Time, Location, `AM/PM`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,

INDEX `DateFK_idx` (`Date` ASC) , 
INDEX `TimeFK_idx` (`Time` ASC) ,
INDEX `AM/PMFK_idx` (`AM/PM` ASC) , 
INDEX `LocationFK_idx` (`Location` ASC)
);


CREATE TABLE `userreg` (
`User Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Real Name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`Email address` varchar(50) DEFAULT 'NONE ON FILE',
`Location` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`User Name`),

CONSTRAINT `userregFK`
FOREIGN KEY (`Location`)
REFERENCES tester.locations (`Location`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,

INDEX `LocationFK_idx` (`Location` ASC)
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems. You must build the `Locations` table before any other tables that reference it. So move that one up to the top.

Then, you will need a matching index for every `FOREIGN KEY` you define.  You have a composite `PRIMARY KEY` of

```
PRIMARY KEY (`Date`,`Time`,`Location`,`AM/PM`)
```

already, so some of your `FOREIGN KEY` definitions will work. However, you will need to create additional indexes for those FK definitions which don't use the full composite `PK`.  This is due to the fact that both the parent and the referencing table must have an index defined across the complete set of columns you use as a `FOREIGN KEY`.

```
# Move this table definition to be first
CREATE TABLE `locations` (
  `Date` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Time` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `AM/PM` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Location` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Location Type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Temperature (F)` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Date`,`Time`,`Location`,`AM/PM`),

  # Added these two keys for the later FK definitions
  # Referenced by generalweatherFK:
  INDEX (`Date`, `Location`),
  # Referenced by userregFK
  INDEX (`Location`)
);
```

Here's the whole thing building properly: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d208e

Comment: Is this because MySql requires an index both on the referencing table and the referenced table? If I remember correctly, on primary keys will be automatically indexed, but will still need to have an index if referenced by another table, correct?

Comment: @Baelix Yes - I was just adding that.  There has to be an index on the referenced table which exactly matches the columns used in the FK def on the referencing table, so even if a column is included in another composite index, you still need to index that column on its own.

Comment: Got it. That's where I was getting confused. Composite keys have always been a bit tricky for me. Thank you. (Side note: this code does work if built from scratch HOWEVER, building any of the other tables before building this one threw the same error for me. Probably due to the fact that locations had already been created, w/o the index)